# issue with rewrite module in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

working on local setup . Found this problem while rewriting URL to look good
I have  department , category and products list ....when i click on one of the department the url is rewritten from

```
Project /index.php?departmentId=1 to
Project/deptname-d1
```

And it displays the associated categories with tat department the twist is when one of the category is selected server throws object not found 
The selected URL was not found on server the link on referring page seems to be wrong or outdated 
The URL before rewriting would be

```
Project/index.php?departmentId=1&CategoryId=2
```

The required format of url is 
Project /deptname-d1/catname-c2
The regex   in htacess is something like this 
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /project
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*/index.(php|html?)\ HTTP
    RewriteRule  ^(.*)index.(php|html?)$  $1 [R=301,L]
    #rewrite rules for department 
    RewriteRule ^.*?-d([0-9]+)/page-([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?   DepartmentId=$1&Page=$2[L]
    RewriteRule ^.*?-d([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?DepartmentId=$1[L]
    #rules for category 
    RewriteRule ^.*-d([0-9]+)/^.*-c([0-9]+)/page-([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?DepartmentId=$1&CategoryId=$2&Page=$3[L]
    RewriteRule ^.*-d([0-9]+)/^.*c([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?DepartmentId=$1&CategoryId=$2 [L]
    #rewrite rules for product 
    Rewriterule ^.*?-p([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?productId=$1

Before rewriting the following were the urls
    localhost/project/          for front page 
    localhost/project/index.php?DepartmentId=x  for department front page 
    localhost/project/index.php?DepartmentId=x&page=zfor department pag
    localhost/project/index.php?DepartmentId=x&CategoryId=y for category front page 
   localhost/project/index.php?DepartmentId=xCategoryId=y&page=z for category pages 
  localhost /project/ProductId=Q
These are the input Urls which are to be rewritten in the following form
    Localhost/project/          for front page 
    localhost/project/department-name-dx/ for department front page 
    localhost/project/department-name-dx/page-z/ for department pages 
    localhost/project/department-name-dx/category-name-cy/ for category front
   localhost/project/department-name-dx/category-name-cy/page-z for category pages

```
Please note tat department and product related regex are working fine only the category page is acting weird can someone explain wats going wrong
```

Comment: Fix your rules in .htaccess, and add this: `RewriteRule Project/deptname-d(\d+)/?$ /index.php?departmentId=$1 [L]`

Comment: No luck ..i tried your method now server throws error 500

Comment: It shouldn't, please post fixed .htaccess

Comment: updated the post please have a look at it ...and suggest somethin

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is wrong. You cannot place `^` in the middle of your regex. Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^.*?-d([0-9]+)/.*?-c([0-9]+)/page-([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?DepartmentId=$1&CategoryId=$2&Page=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^.*?-d([0-9]+)/.*?c([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?DepartmentId=$1&CategoryId=$2 [L,QSA]
```

I suggest you to provide all the input URLs in your question.

Comment: Yeah jus now have look at it and sorry it was upted via mobile